Celestron X-Cel Barlow 2x magnification or Celestron X-Cel LX eyepiece 5 mm for 250P Dobsonian Sky-Watcher Telescope
I have recently gotten a Dobsonian 250P Sky-Watcher telescope and just wanted to ask whether it would be better to get a Celestron X-Cel Barlow 2× magnification or Celestron X-Cel LX 5 mm eyepiece. The default eyepieces that come with the telescope are the 10 mm and 25 mm, but I was looking for a nice upgrade to the collection of eyepieces. Both the 5 mm and Celestron Barlow are quality pieces, but I wanted to know whether it would be better to get one or the other or even both. My main goal is visual planetary astronomy but also nebulae and galaxies.

This really comes down to the usual sky conditions at your observing location.
If you generally have good seeing and transparency then I would go for the 5mm eyepiece because you'll be able to use it.
If you don't, then go for the Barlow.
The reason is that under bad seeing conditions a 5mm eyepiece in that telescope will give a blurry image because it won't be able to handle the high magnification. A Barlow would be more useful because you can use it with multiple eyepieces. And for the handful of nights a year with good seeing then you can Barlow your 10mm.

I'm quite lucky where I am in that I get many nights of good seeing in a year, and can use even 3.3mm and 4mm eyepieces fairly frequently.
I have a telescope that's the same aperture and focal length as yours.


An eyepiece designed for high magnification will always give a better image than a Barlow. That's just a crude (but clever) kludge -- a negative lens shoved into the optical path.

This is generally but not always true.  A barlow can let you use longer-focal-length eyepieces which allow greater eye-relief, which is sometimes a necessity (if you need to wear glasses for example)

Ooo, good point.

While the answer by Miss_Understands is right that a single eyepiece will give better images as opposed to an eyepiece-plus-Barlow combination, and while antlersoft's comment is right that a Barlow can help those who need longer eye relief, there are other factors at play.
I don’t know all the details about your telescope, as I’m not familiar with the “250P” by Sky-Watcher, but I own a very similar telescope: a 10-inch Sky-Watcher SynScan “goto” telescope on Dobsonian mount. Optically, it’s probably the same, but mine is motorized; not sure about yours. If yours is motorized, I would advise against using higher magnification powers, as the guiding system gives “bumps” that are annoying at high magnifications — the drive is not smooth but done by stepper motors.
Another thing is you’re asking about a 5 mm eyepiece, while you already have a 10 mm eyepiece. Using a 2× Barlow would give the same result, so why not get it and another eyepiece (if your budget allows it, but you mention the possibility, so I suppose it does), but not the 5 mm one? For example, a 6 mm or a 3 mm. This way, you’d have different powers and not just a repeat of the same ones.
